# Problems with upgrade from a Windows Phone 7.5 project to WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to maintain two versions of my app targeting WP7.5 and WP8. I started with the WP7.5 app and added a copy of the project with linked files. Then I upgraded the "linked" project to WP8 via the Visual Studio command. When I run the WP8 app on the emulator it crashes with a `System.InvalidOperationException in System.Windows.ni.dll` when executing a `MessageBox.Show()` command. The output windows shows a `FileNotFoundException in mscorlib.ni.dll` before the error message previously mentioned.

I tried adding mscorlib.dll to the WP8 project, but VS tells me it's already referenced. I also tried setting all capabilites in WMAppManifest as seen in similar threads but the problem is still alive. Can anyone give me a hint?

Below is my output after execution. I hope you don't mind the german.

[image]

Comment: On WP8 MessageBox is defined in `System.Windows.dll`. Path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\System.Windows.dll`

Comment: When you're building the project, do you get any warnings? Also, in what way did you "link" the projects?

Comment: I tried adding the dll but it does appear in the references afterwards and there is no error while adding. It just does not work... I have no compiler warnings and I created a copy of the project, deleted all shared files and readded them via the "as link" option in the file dialog.

Comment: Found solution, maybe I should have mentioned that I am calling `MessageBox.Show()` within the Application_Launching handler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Windows 8 Windows Phone 8: In Windows Phone 8 if you call Show method from the app Activated or Launching event handlers an InvalidOperationException is thrown with the message Error Displaying MessageBox. Alternatively, you should call the Show method from the Page.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs) method.`

Found that in MSDN and this applies to my situation. That was exactly my problem.